# Android Export aborted because fatal error were founds

Tags: android, export, apk, signed

I can't export signed or unsigned application package

```
*Export Aborted
Export aborted because fatal Lin error were founds. These are listed in the
problems view. Either fix these before running Export Again, or turn off "Run
full error check when exporting app" in the Android > Lint Error Cheking preference page.*
```

---

**Solution**:

```
Window>Preferences>Android>Lint Error Checking

uncheck Run full error check when exporting app
```

Comment: Maybe you could cite these errors, listed in the problems view?

Comment: To solve issue: Project -> properties, find Android Lint Preferences, in top to right click configure workspace settings... -> unclick "Run full error check when exporting app", apply done.

Comment: I found that the error was because not all String values have a matching string on the international files. MissingTranslation is an Error by default, and the error does not appear in the "Problems" view, or the "Lint Warnings" view.

Comment: http://androidroadies.blogspot.in/2013/08/android-export-aborted-because-fatal.html

Comment: @Warpzit Its not working for me. can you please help me to resolve it?

Comment: @PravinsinghWaghela try again. This is caused by lint errors so you need to disable the lint checks or actually fixing the errors.

Comment: @Warpzit Well Thanks I just find the solution.